# ArrayList<String> delete query

Tags: java, string, arraylist, java.util.scanner, delete-row

Here's my output:

```
-----Query-----
[1]Update
[2]Delete
[3]Search
[4]Show
Choose Query:1
Enter Your Student ID:1
Enter Your First Name: Respo
Enter Your Middle Name: Topher
Enter Your Last Name: Raspo
Do you want to back to Query?(Yes/No)
Yes
-----Query-----
[1]Update
[2]Delete
[3]Search
[4]Show
Choose Query: 4
12
Christopher
Reposo
Porras
1
Respo
Topher
Raspo
```

As you can see in the picture I'm trying to make a simple little system without database but using ArrayList to contain those data now my problem is in the Delete Query. Now in Delete Query I tell the user to type the student number which is 1 then delete the information of it and its contain which is first name, middle name, last name But I don't have much logic in ArrayList to do such thing. By the way is it possible to use only One ArrayList in this case or I need to make many array list to solve my problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //initialize Scanner for input process
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //initialize needs variable
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    int choose,chooseQuery;
    String chooseYesOrNo = " ";
    String chooseYesOrNo2 = " ";    

    do {
        //Startup Program
        System.out.println("=====-----LibrarySystem-----=====");
        System.out.println("[1]Student Information");
        System.out.println("[2]Book Information");
        System.out.print("Choose Table:");
        choose = scan.nextInt();

        do {            
            if(choose == 1) {
                System.out.println("-----Query-----");
                System.out.println("[1]Update");
                System.out.println("[2]Delete");
                System.out.println("[3]Search");
                System.out.println("[4]Show");
                //reserved
                //reserved
                System.out.print("Choose Query:");
                chooseQuery = scan.nextInt();

                if(chooseQuery == 1) {                    
                    System.out.print("Enter Your Student ID:");
                    String id = scan.next();
                    list.add(id);
                    System.out.print("Enter Your First Name:");
                    String name = scan.next();
                    list.add(name);
                    System.out.print("Enter Your Middle Name:");
                    String middle_name = scan.next();
                    list.add(middle_name);
                    System.out.print("Enter Your Last Name:");
                    String last_name = scan.next();
                    list.add(last_name);          

                    System.out.println("Do you want to back to Query?(Yes/No)");
                    chooseYesOrNo = scan.next();                             
                } else if (chooseQuery == 2) { //Delete Query
                    System.out.print("Enter Student ID:");
                    String find_id = scan.next();                               
                } else if(chooseQuery == 3) { //Search Query

                } else if(chooseQuery == 4) { //Show Query
                    for (String s : list) {
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                }
            }
        } while(chooseYesOrNo.equals("Yes"));

        System.out.println("Do you want to get back at tables?(Yes/No)");
        chooseYesOrNo2 = scan.next();                                   
    } while(chooseYesOrNo2.equals("Yes"));

    System.out.println("-----=====Program Terminated=====-----");
}
```

Comment: Don't post pictures, post text.

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the code you have right now.

Comment: my fault i will post it right away

Comment: Have you learned about classes yet? This will be much easier if you create a `Student` class to gather all of the data together in a single object.

Comment: not yet sir but i will try to study about classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create Student object which contains all the fields you need (student id, name, etc)

   ```
   class Student {
     int studentId;
     String firstname;
     String middlename;
     String lastname;
   }
   ```
2. Have one array list for Student objects

   ```
   java.util.List<Student> list = new java.util.ArrayList<Student>();
   ```
3. When Delete operation is selected, iterate through your list to find the object and remove it. Here's [nice blog](http://crunchify.com/how-to-iterate-through-java-list-4-way-to-iterate-through-loop/) about ways to iterate through arraylist. My favorite method is as follows:

   ```
   for (Student std:list) {
     if (std.studentId == targetId) {
       list.remove(std);
       break; //since you've removed target, you can exit the loop
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Sir Ryan i have problem regarding in this code .

for (Student std:list) {
  if (std.studentId == targetId) {
    list.remove(std);
    break; //since you've removed target, you can exit the loop
  }
}

i got error and it says object cannot converted to list

i know its too much spoonfeeding in me im sorry.